# how can i log in my website seamlessly using facebook credentials , when i'm already logged in my facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

how can i login my website using facebook credentials that too seamlessly , when i'm already logged in my facebook account in the same session or in another session. For example i'm logged in my fb and when i open website named rottentomatoes.com in the same session or in another session , i can get automatically logged in , without doing anything , as that site use my fb account and automatically get a registered memeber of that site.

i wanna do this things in my website , like things happening with rotten tomatoes.

so far i can use fb account to login in my website using facebook connect .

please help me ....any suggestion will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a facebook app, then in your site use the [facebook js sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

You always have different sessions per site, you'll need to make a session for yours, you don't use the facebook session, just the sdk.

When the user loads your page you can use the [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to check if the user is logged into facebook and is authenticated with your app, if so then you get the needed user data and can then log the user into your site.

If the user is not logged into facebook, or hasn't authorized your app then you can use the [FB.login method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to log the user in, when the user comes back from that process you should have the data you need in order to register/log him into your site.